# ASP.Net Scaffolded MVC Struggling to populate a dropdownlist with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm struggling to conceptualise this because every resource I have found on Google has presented a different way to do it.

I have, at the moment generated razor views pertaining to a scaffolded controller using entity Framework. My controller looks like this:

```
    // GET: tbl_computerinfo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tbl_computerinfo = db.tbl_computerinfo.Include(t => t.tbl_equipment);
        tbl_computerinfo = tbl_computerinfo.Where(c => c.Company == "Company Name");
        return View(tbl_computerinfo.ToList());
    }
```

My Model is quite large but is just a generated entity framework model built on two tables linked with a foreign key tbl_computerinfo and tbl_equipment.

There is a string field called company in tbl_computerinfo. I need to select all the unique company values in the database and then use that to populate a dropdown which would exist on the index view. The selection of a company on that dropdown list should then filter the results in index view to only pull back entries with that company name. Any pointing in the right direction would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Getting the company info? Populating the selectlist?

Comment: I can understand the concept of getting the company list into a selectlistitem, I can also get behind the razor code which is simple but then not sure how to include it in the return view listed in the code I posted as it is already returning tbl_computerinfo.tolist()

Comment: ok, so you need to create a `ViewModel`. At the moment you're just passing a `List` to the View.  Create a class with a `List` property and pass the class to the view.

Comment: But then how do I pass the current tbl_computerinfo as well? I don't understand how I can pass the list AND the tbl_computerinfo model?

Comment: I'll add an answer as it's impossible to write code in these comment boxes.  I'm not sure what information you actually want to pass to the view, but this is the approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a ViewModel:

```
public class ComputerInfoViewModel
{
    public List<string> CompanyList {get; set;}
    public ComputerInfo ComputerInfo {get; set;}
}
```

In your Index method you populate this and pass it to the View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ComputerInfoViewModel
        {
            CompanyList = /* populate this with your list of companies  */
            ComputerInfo = /* populate this with what? */
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

In your View, you declare the model:

```
@model ComputerInfoViewModel
```

And you can access the model properties for display using `@Model.CompanyList` and `@Model.ComputerInfo`